# Exceeded time limit on Trie search with Backtracking using Swift

Tags: recursion, swift, depth-first-search, trie, backtracking

I have been trying to solve **Trie** related problems over at leet code and came across this interesting problem [211. Design Add and Search Words Data Structure](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-add-and-search-words-data-structure/)

Here is the question for convenience:

**211. Design Add and Search Words Data Structure**

> Design a data structure that supports adding new words and finding if a string matches any previously added string.
>
> Implement the WordDictionary class:
>
> **WordDictionary()** Initializes the object.
>
> **void addWord(word)** Adds word to the data structure, it can be matched later.
>
> **bool search(word)** Returns true if there is any string in the data structure that matches word or false otherwise. word may contain dots '.' where dots can be matched with any letter.
>
> **Example:**
>
> **Input**
>
> ["WordDictionary","addWord","addWord","addWord","search","search","search","search"]
>
> [[],["bad"],["dad"],["mad"],["pad"],["bad"],[".ad"],["b.."]] Output
> [null,null,null,null,false,true,true,true]
>
> **Explanation**
>
> WordDictionary wordDictionary = new WordDictionary();
>
> wordDictionary.addWord("bad"); wordDictionary.addWord("dad");
>
> wordDictionary.addWord("mad"); wordDictionary.search("pad"); // return
>
> False wordDictionary.search("bad"); // return True
>
> wordDictionary.search(".ad"); // return True
>
> wordDictionary.search("b.."); // return True
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> `1 <= word.length <= 25`
>
> `word` in `addWord` consists of lowercase English letters.
>
> `word` in `search` consist of '.' or lowercase English letters.
>
> There will be at most 3 dots in word for `search` queries.
>
> At most 10<sup>4</sup> calls will be made to `addWord` and `search`.

I got some help yesterday with a [similar question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/279409/leet-code-139-word-break-using-a-trie-with-recursion) on how to optimize my **Trie** implementation and tried my best to incorporate those into my solution to this question.

I got a solution to work with Trie and backtracking, however, I once again ran into the Time Limit exceeded conundrum.

I came across this Python solution on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTf05gs_8iU&ab_channel=NeetCode) and tried to implement it using Swift, however that did not help.

Here is the search function:

```
private class WordDictionary {
    var root: TrieNode
    
    class TrieNode {
        var next = [Character: TrieNode]()
        var isWordEnd = false
    }
    
    init() {
        root = TrieNode()
    }
    
    func addWord(_ word: String) {
        var node = root
        
        for char in word {
            node = addInternal(char, at: node)
        }
        
        node.isWordEnd = true
    }
    
    func addInternal(_ char: Character, at node: TrieNode) -> TrieNode {
        if let nextNode = node.next[char] {
            return nextNode
        }
        
        let nextNode = TrieNode()
        node.next[char] = nextNode
        return nextNode
    }
    
    func search(_ word: String) -> Bool {
        
        func dfs(index: String.Index, at node: TrieNode) -> Bool {
            var currentNode = node
            var currentIndex = index
            
            while currentIndex < word.endIndex {
                let currentChar = word[currentIndex]
                
                if currentChar == "." {
                    if let nextNodes = Array(currentNode.next.values) as? [TrieNode] {
                        
                        for nextNode in nextNodes {
                            var nextIndex = currentIndex
                            word.formIndex(after: &nextIndex)
                            
                            if dfs(index: nextIndex, at: nextNode) {
                                return true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    return false
                }
                
                if let nextNode = currentNode.next[currentChar] {
                    currentNode = nextNode
                    word.formIndex(after: &currentIndex)
                    continue
                }
                
                return false
            }
            
            return currentNode.isWordEnd
        }
        
        return dfs(index: word.startIndex, at: root)
    }
}
```

This seems to be working correctly on these test cases:

```
private func test1() {
    let wordDictionary = WordDictionary()
    wordDictionary.addWord("baad")
    wordDictionary.addWord("dad")
    wordDictionary.addWord("mad")
    print(wordDictionary.search("baa")) // return False
    print(wordDictionary.search("bad")) // return False
    print(wordDictionary.search("baad")) // return True
    print(wordDictionary.search(".ad")) // return True
    print(wordDictionary.search("b..d")) // return True
    print(wordDictionary.search("pad")) // return False
    print(wordDictionary.search("bad")) // return False
    print(wordDictionary.search("b.ad")) // return True
    print(wordDictionary.search("mad")) // return True
    print(wordDictionary.search("bam")) // return False
}

private func test2() {
    let wordDictionary = WordDictionary()
    wordDictionary.addWord("a")
    wordDictionary.addWord("a")
    print(wordDictionary.search(".")) // return True
    print(wordDictionary.search("a")) // return True
    print(wordDictionary.search("aa")) // return False
    print(wordDictionary.search("a")) // return True
    print(wordDictionary.search(".a")) // return False
    print(wordDictionary.search("a.")) // return False
}
```

However, I get a time limit exceeded exception on [this test case](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/791316693/testcase/)

I am not sure where the bottle neck and as at first glance, I cannot see any opportunity for memoization to improve the performance.

I am sure there might be other / more optimal solutions besides using a Trie, however, I am trying to get an optimal solution using a Trie since I am currently trying to improve my understanding of this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good job in incorporating the feedback from your previous question to improve the Trie implementation.

The `dfs()` function can be improved a bit: Creating an array of all successor nodes (in the case of a wildcard character)

```
if let nextNodes = Array(currentNode.next.values) as? [TrieNode] {
    for nextNode in nextNodes {
        // ...
    }
}
```

is not necessary, one can iterate over the values directly:

```
for nextNode in currentNode.next.values {
    // ...
}
```

The variable

```
var nextIndex = currentIndex
word.formIndex(after: &nextIndex)
```

can be made a constant with

```
let nextIndex = word.index(currentIndex, offsetBy: 1)
```

Also

```
if let nextNode = currentNode.next[currentChar] {
    currentNode = nextNode
    word.formIndex(after: &currentIndex)
    continue
}

return false
```

is in my opinion better written with an `else` block instead of `continue`:

```
if let nextNode = currentNode.next[currentChar] {
    currentNode = nextNode
    word.formIndex(after: &currentIndex)
} else {
    return false
}
```

#### Caching the results

In the test case that fails with a timeout error, the same string “ghkdnjmmgcddganjkigmabbho” is searched 5000 times. So caching *does* help. It can be easily added to the search function. Note that the cache must be invalidated if a new word is added to the dictionary:

```
class WordDictionary {
    var root: TrieNode
    var cache: [String: Bool] = [:]
    // ...    

    func addWord(_ word: String) {
        // ...
        cache.removeAll()
    }
    
    // ...    

    func search(_ word: String) -> Bool {
        if let result = cache[word] {
            return result
        }
        
        func dfs(index: String.Index, at node: TrieNode) -> Bool {
            // ...
        }
        
        let result = dfs(index: word.startIndex, at: root)
        cache[word] = result
        return result
    }
}
```

This can be optimized further:

- Repeated calls to `cache.removeAll()` can be avoided. Instead of emptying the cash in `addWord()`, set an “invalid” flag and empty the cache in the `search()` method if that flag is set.
- `true` entries in the cache remain valid if a new word is added to the dictionary. So instead of completely emptying the cache if a new word has been added, remove only the `false` entries.

The code then looks like this:

```
class WordDictionary {
    var root: TrieNode
    var cache: [String: Bool] = [:]
    var cacheValid = true
    
    class TrieNode {
        var next = [Character: TrieNode]()
        var isWordEnd = false
    }
    
    init() {
        root = TrieNode()
    }
    
    func addWord(_ word: String) {
        var node = root
        
        for char in word {
            node = addInternal(char, at: node)
        }
        
        node.isWordEnd = true
        cacheValid = false
    }
    
    func addInternal(_ char: Character, at node: TrieNode) -> TrieNode {
        if let nextNode = node.next[char] {
            return nextNode
        }
        
        let nextNode = TrieNode()
        node.next[char] = nextNode
        return nextNode
    }
    
    func search(_ word: String) -> Bool {
        if (!cacheValid) {
            let falseKeys = cache.compactMap { $0.value == false ? $0.key : nil }
            for key in falseKeys {
                cache[key] = nil
            }
            cacheValid = true
        } else if let result = cache[word] {
            return result
        }
        
        func dfs(index: String.Index, at node: TrieNode) -> Bool {
            var currentNode = node
            var currentIndex = index
            
            while currentIndex < word.endIndex {
                let currentChar = word[currentIndex]
                
                if currentChar == "." {
                    for nextNode in currentNode.next.values {
                        let nextIndex = word.index(currentIndex, offsetBy: 1)
                        if dfs(index: nextIndex, at: nextNode) {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    return false
                }
                
                if let nextNode = currentNode.next[currentChar] {
                    currentNode = nextNode
                    word.formIndex(after: &currentIndex)
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
            
            return currentNode.isWordEnd
        }
        
        let result = dfs(index: word.startIndex, at: root)
        cache[word] = result
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Martin. I submitted with the cached improvements, however I still get the time limit exceeded, although with a different test case so I think there is an improvement. I think I need to go further with the last 2 points. I keep the true values using `filter`. Regarding filtering the hash in search, can you please elaborate on when I should perform this operation? Is it when the cache does not have the result or when we are trying to add a new word to a hash or some other time ?

Comment: It is currently failing on: https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/791809726/testcase/

Comment: @ShawnFrank: That is strange, my code passed all tests even before implementing the last two points. But I have added the final code for your convenience.

Comment: Works great once I added your `if (!cacheValid) {` logic. If I could ask a couple of last clarifications. 1 - In the `!cacheValid`, I initially did `cache = cache.filter { key, value in return value == true  }` to only keep the true values although this again runs into time limit exceeded, is there something more optimal with your solution of validating the cache with `compact map`? 2 - The Python solution in the video did not use any caching, do you have any idea what operations in Swift underperform that might require this additional measure ? Thanks again for your help !

Comment: @ShawnFrank: 1) Good question. `filter` is the natural way to remove the outdated entries, I don't know why that is so slow. I tried different methods, and what I showed turned out to be the fastest one. Perhaps I will investigate that further when I find the time. – 2) I do not know.